# Is it possible to get a Swiss Work Permit (with a job offer) while retaining my German settlement permit (Niederlassungserlaubnis)?

Tags: germany, residency, switzerland, work-permit

I understand that the rules state: if we leave Germany for more than 6 months consecutively, we would lose the settlement permit

If I live in Switzerland (with a Swiss residence permit), and make trips back to Germany frequently every month for example, is there a way to keep my German settlement permit?

The reason is that perhaps in the future I may decide to move completely back to Germany.

Since Switzerland is in the Schengen, is there really any indication/record if I "leave"?

Essentially I will not be a tax resident in Germany, and will not be claiming any welfare. I will be earning and paying tax in Switzerland. I will still have my apartment back in Germany though.

Comment: Do you plan to remain registered  at your German address?

Comment: The Swiss work permit and job offers are essentially irrelevant. You can get it, you will still have your *Niederlassungserlaubnis*. The question is whether you can work in Switzerland long term and retain a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*.

Comment: What about your car? Your driving license? Your health insurance?

Comment: Would have an apartment in Germany still, driving license also to remain German. Insurance i know I'll need one in CH, so not sure if I'll need an extra one in Germany too (but willing to have it).

Comment: driving license also to remain German I doubt that would be possible, you are required to exchange your DL for a Swiss one within a year of getting your Swiss RP

Comment: You may be able to avail of the G cross border worker permit. But this is better to be asked to a German immigration lawyer